# How do I restore redundancy to an LVM-RAID volume

Tags: linux, lvm, raid

I have a logical volume (home64) that spans several drives that was converted to RAID1 using lvconvert.

This was fine, and when a drive failed, it carried on. Now I'm trying to replace the drive however I seem to have got it into a bit of a state.

I created a PV on the new drive and added it to the VG with vgextend.

I've been unable to get the LV to use the additional space and "undegrade" it.

I've tried repairing it, but it appeared to require the failed drive before it would run. (I don't have the output from these commands, unfortunately)

```bsh
# /dev/sda is the new disk.
sudo lvconvert --repair /dev/mapper/prole-home64 /dev/sda
```

(**edit**) I reran the command. The failed drive was 8TB, I had replaced it with another 8TB drive, and had some additional space remaining on other volumes that should cover the rounding error in "8TB".

This command shows less space as I've started putting the fallback plan (at the bottom) into effect.

```
sudo lvconvert --repair /dev/mapper/prole-home64
  WARNING: Disabling lvmetad cache for repair command.
  WARNING: Not using lvmetad because of repair.
Attempt to replace failed RAID images (requires full device resync)? [y/n]: y
  Insufficient free space: 5240758 extents needed, but only 1560 available
  Failed to replace faulty devices in prole/home64.
```

(**/edit**)

I tried to replace the failed drive, but am not sure how to refer to an absent drive:

```bsh
# Mc2wIK-... is the PV id as mentioned in /etc/lvm/backup/prole
sudo lvconvert --replace Mc2wIK-qrme-cjBN-LArd-S4je-x2p0-p7qke1 /dev/mapper/prole-home64 /dev/sda

# pv1 is the label of the group in /etc/lvm/backup/prole
sudo lvconvert --replace pv1 /dev/mapper/prole-home64 /dev/sda
```

Neither of these appear to have had any effect.

`lvconvert` did suggest that perhaps I wanted to try `vgreduce --removemissing`

So I did. It failed due to active volumes. As the drive was already failed, I forced removal:

```
sudo vgreduce --removemissing prole
sudo vgreduce --removemissing prole --force
```

I then learned about `lvchange --syncaction`. I ran it on a smaller volumes that was also affected by the drive failure, found problems, and repaired them:

```bsh
lvchange --syncaction check /dev/mapper/prole-root

# Monitor progress by repeatedly running this:
lvs -a -o name,raid_sync_action,sync_percent

# Get the result with this:
lvs -o name,raid_mismatch_count

# Actually repair the volume
lvchange --syncaction repair /dev/prole/root
```

This **was** successful.

However when I try to do this on the large volume, it "completes" instantly, without recording any errors.

If I try to get the health status of the volume:

```
sudo lvs -o name,lv_health_status
  LV     Health
  home
  home64 refresh needed
  root
  var
```

If I try to refresh the volume:

```
sudo lvchange --refresh /dev/prole/home64
  Failed to remove temporary SubLVs from prole/home64
```

This shows some problems:

```
sudo lvs -a -o name,segtype,devices
  LV                Type   Devices
  home              linear /dev/sda(0)
  home              linear /dev/sde(0)
  home              linear /dev/sdb(1793)
  home64            raid1  home64_rimage_0(0),home64_rimage_1(0)
  [home64_rimage_0] error
  [home64_rimage_1] linear /dev/sdg(1)
  [home64_rimage_1] linear /dev/sdh(0)
  [home64_rimage_1] linear /dev/sdf(3330)
  [home64_rimage_1] linear /dev/sdf(1428550)
  [home64_rimage_1] linear /dev/sdd(1335820)
  [home64_rmeta_0]  error
  [home64_rmeta_1]  linear /dev/sdg(0)
  root              raid1  root_rimage_0(0),root_rimage_1(0)
  [root_rimage_0]   linear /dev/sdd(1810605)
  [root_rimage_1]   linear /dev/sdf(1)
  [root_rmeta_0]    linear /dev/sdd(856646)
  [root_rmeta_1]    linear /dev/sdf(0)
  var               raid1  var_rimage_0(0),var_rimage_1(0)
  [var_rimage_0]    linear /dev/sdb(1)
  [var_rimage_1]    linear /dev/sdf(2050)
  [var_rimage_1]    linear /dev/sdf(949475)
  [var_rmeta_0]     linear /dev/sdb(0)
  [var_rmeta_1]     linear /dev/sdf(2049)
```

How do I restore redundancy to the volume?

(My fallback plan is to create another volume, copy the contents of the home64 volume to it, remove the home64 volume, then convert the new volume to RAID1, but there must be a better way!)

Comment: The fallback plan failed; I have a lot of files with multiple hardlinks that I hadn't considered, so just copying all the files ran out of space.

Answer (score 1):

I realised I could make some more space available by reducing the PVs that the home64 volume was spread across by calling running `pvmove` with the PVs to move from and two. This, plus another 6TB I had available, plus the 8TB from the replacement disk, left me enough space to repair the LV with `lvchange --syncaction repair /dev/prole/home`.

Here's what it looks like now:

```
sudo lvs -a -o name,segtype,devices
  WARNING: Not using lvmetad because a repair command was run.
  LV                Type   Devices
  home64            raid1  home64_rimage_0(0),home64_rimage_1(0)
  [home64_rimage_0] linear /dev/sdf(1)
  [home64_rimage_0] linear /dev/sda(0)
  [home64_rimage_0] linear /dev/sdc2(0)
  [home64_rimage_1] linear /dev/sdg(1)
  [home64_rimage_1] linear /dev/sdi(0)
  [home64_rimage_1] linear /dev/sdb(3842)
  [home64_rimage_1] linear /dev/sdd(1335820)
  [home64_rmeta_0]  linear /dev/sdf(0)
  [home64_rmeta_1]  linear /dev/sdg(0)
  root              raid1  root_rimage_0(0),root_rimage_1(0)
  [root_rimage_0]   linear /dev/sdd(1810605)
  [root_rimage_1]   linear /dev/sdb(1)
  [root_rmeta_0]    linear /dev/sdd(856646)
  [root_rmeta_1]    linear /dev/sdb(0)
  var               raid1  var_rimage_0(0),var_rimage_1(0)
  [var_rimage_0]    linear /dev/sdd(0)
  [var_rimage_1]    linear /dev/sdb(2050)
  [var_rmeta_0]     linear /dev/sdd(1812653)
  [var_rmeta_1]     linear /dev/sdb(2049)
```

Health status:

```
sudo lvs -o name,lv_health_status
  WARNING: Not using lvmetad because a repair command was run.
  LV     Health
  home64
  root
  var
```

Comment: Thanks for your question and answer(s) :-)  Do you know what that warning is there for and why is hasn't gone away?  Does it go away eventually?  Or does it require some action (e.g. reboot)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. The warning has gone away now, but this is over two years later and the OS has been upgraded at least once since then.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found out it is caused by changes to physical volumes (e.g. a device disappearing or appearing).  If one runs pvscan then it seems to go away.